# Python regex error: raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)

Tags: python, regex

I want to change the tags of tables by using the following function. It works for some documents. For other documents, I encountered the following error. What is causing this? Thank you!

My function:

```
def tag_tables(rawtext):
    pattern_table = r"(<table.*?>(.*?)</table>)"
    tables = re.findall(pattern_table, rawtext, flags=re.I | re.S)


    table_count = len(tables)

    if table_count == 0:
        return rawtext, table_count

    for table, table_string in tables:
        re_table = re.escape(table)
        rawtext = re.sub(re_table, "\n#TABLE#@\n" + table_string + 
                 "\n##TABLE##@\n", rawtext, 1, flags=re.I | re.S)

    return rawtext, table_count
```

The error:

```
 File "C:/Users/Victor Wang/PycharmProjects/OCI/parse_OCI_files_stage 
    1_20191017.py", line 180, in tag_tables
   rawtext = re.sub(re_table, "\n#TABLE#@\n" + table_string + 
   "\n##TABLE##@\n", rawtext, 1, flags=re.I | re.S)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 326, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 317, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 943, in parse_template
    addgroup(int(this[1:]), len(this) - 1)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 887, in addgroup
    raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
   sre_constants.error: invalid group reference 15 at position 2747 (line 
   116, column 17)
```

Comment: A group reference is a component of a regex that refers to a previously captured group. It usually looks like a slash followed by a number, for example "\15". Do you have a "\15" in your `re_table` string? If you do, and you have less than fifteen capturing groups, then the regex will fail to compile.

Comment: Indeed, I have "\15" in the text.  re.escape does not address it?  Please provide your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: This is useless to do a replacement in two steps (1. search string with `re.findall`, 2. loop over the results and replace with `re.sub`) when you can do the same thing in one step with `re.sub`.

Comment: You're correct.